# OpenMP matrix-vector multiplication on-the-fly in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, matrix-multiplication, lanczos

I am writing a Fortran code to carry out a matrix-vector multiplication. The multiplication is carried out on-the-fly in the sense that the matrix elements are not stored beforehand. The code goes well in the serial case, but when I implement the parallelized case with OpenMP as the following, I can't get the correct output.  May someone suggests what I did wrong?

```
Module module1
   integer:: N, M
   integer, allocatable:: Jeven_A(:), Jeven_B(:), Jodd_A(:), Jodd_B(:), s(:)
END module module1

subroutine lookup(a,Pswitch,sa)
    use module1
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in):: a, Pswitch
    integer, intent(out):: sa
    integer:: Ia, Ib

    Ib = ibits(a,N/2,N/2)
    Ia = ibits(a,0,N/2)
    if (Pswitch==0) then
        sa = Jeven_A(Ia)+Jeven_B(Ib)
    else if (Pswitch==1) then
        sa = Jodd_A(Ia)+Jodd_B(Ib)
    end if
end subroutine lookup

SUBROUTINE Mv_onthefly(V, vni, vno)
    USE module1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN):: vni, vno
    complex, DIMENSION(1:M,1:3):: V
    INTEGER::sb, i,j ,k, a, b
    complex, allocatable:: Vvni(:), Vvno(:)

    allocate(Vvni(1:M),Vvno(1:M))
    Do i=1, M
        Vvni(i) = V(i,vni)
    END DO
    Vvno = 0.

!$OMP PARALLEL private(k,i,j,sb,a,b,bittest,Vvni)
!$OMP DO REDUCTION(+:Vvno)
   DO k=1,M
       a = s(k) 
       b = 0
       DO i=0, N-1
            Do j=0, N-1
                  b = IEOR(a,2**i+2**j)
                  CALL lookup(b,0,sb)  !subroutine which lookup the index sb corresponds to b in the array s
                  Vvno(sb)=Vvno(sb)-J1*Vvni(k)
            END do
        END DO
        DO i=0, N-1
            Vvno(k)=Vvno(k)-J2*Vvni(k)
        END DO
    END DO
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

   Do i =1, M
       V(i,vno)=Vvno(i)
   END DO
   deallocate(Vvni,Vvno)

END SUBROUTINE Mv_onthefly
```

Comment: If there is wrong output, you should show s how much does the output differ and also the code should be complete, instead of *... some operation to find sb*.

Comment: The `sb` can actually be the key. I see a potential for a race condition in `Vvno`. Also The first loop `Vvno(sb)=Vvno(sb)-J1*Vvni(k)` is potentially in conflict with `Vvno(k)=Vvno(k)-J2*Vvni(k)` from a different thread depending on the value of `sb`. **We need the full code.**

Comment: The detail of the code is added. Thanks.

Comment: Subroutine `lookup` may also need to be necessary. Is it even thread-safe?

Comment: Or why is Vvni private at all?

Comment: I removed Vvni from private and the code works now. However I don't quite understand why Vvni should not be private. In my understanding, setting Vvni to private means that every thread will have a copy of Vvni before parallelization and the value of Vvni should not be changed among the threads. Is my understanding correct?